# Unable to connect to database server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to connect to a database before my "checkusername".

`database.php` in folder config:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'bmc';
//$db['default']['database'] = 'bmc_void';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = "3306";
```

But it returns: `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings`.

Here is the part of function I used to connect database

```
$querysql = "SELECT * 
               FROM `bmc_admin_login` 
               WHERE `admin_name` = '" . $user_name . "' ";

$db=$this->load->database();
//echo "querysql:".$querysql."<br>";
$query = $this->db->query ( $querysql );
$user = $query->row ();
//echo count($user);
if (! isset ( $user ) || ! is_object ( $user ) || count ( $user ) == 0) {
    $this->form_validation->_error_array ['admin_pass_error'] = '您填写的帐号不存在';
    return false;
}
if ($user->admin_pass != $password) {
    $this->form_validation->_error_array ['admin_pass_error'] = '请输入正确的密码';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: are you sure your username and password is correct ?

Comment: MySQL is configured to allowed only a binding from localhost. Go to `my.cnf` and try to comment this line: `bind 127.0.0.1`...

Comment: No need to load database. The default one will be already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What version of CI do you use? I'm using 2.3 and I have this configuration and it's working. And your `db_debug` is equal to `FALSE` try this configuration. Hope it helps.

```
 $active_group = 'default';
 $active_record = TRUE;

 $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
 $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
 $db['default']['password'] = '';
 $db['default']['database'] = 'bmc';
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
 $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
 $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
 $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
 $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
 $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
 $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
 $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I have turnede it to "TRUE", and it tells me I have a error when connecting ...the wrong line it shows is "$this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');" in DB_driver.php

Comment: Did you try removing the `port`? And are you sure your `Apache` and `MYSQL` is running?

Comment: I use wamp to manage apache and mysql...so I'm sure that they are running~